# Publishing more then one chrome extension as a single item in the Google store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Chrome extensions and chrome apps have APIs I need to implement some functionality, and I can't do it with extension only or app only or with native code. So I made an extension and an app and made them to communicate each other via messages. Everything works fine, but now I have to publish it and here's the issue:

*my app is useless without my extension and extension won't work without an app.*

I'm afraid, that if I will publish this items separately, people will be scared if I'll suggest them to install an additional app/extension after they installed one of described items.

*Is there any way to pack two items to a single package and publish it?* Or may be make two packages a single item in the store? Or just connect them some way to make users install booth in one click, or just inform them that this item requires another one to be installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible. Even the popular app/extension Snagit tells users to install the other component in the description!